# Variable file in Expect script

Tags: expect, suse

I'm using this expect script as an answerfile to a interactive shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./interactivescriptname
expect "Question 1?"
send "something\r"
expect "Question 2?"
send "yes\r"
expect "Password?"
send "somepassword\r"
interact
```

above works, but i want to use variables from a inputfile.

my variables files look like this:

```
var1="something"
var2="yes"
var3="somepassword"
```

Normally in bash i would use the source command, but this doesn't work in expect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to set TCL variables in a file (here, `vars`) and then `source` that file from the main script.

```
$ cat vars  
set var1 something
set var2 yes
set var3 Hunter2
$ cat script 
#!/usr/bin/env expect
source vars
puts $var3
$ chmod +x script
$ ./script 
Hunter2
$
```

It may be good to use more informative variable names than `varN` ...